# Print Dialogue for formated R Shiny Output

Tags: r, formatting, shiny

Using R-Shiny, I would like to be able to create a button that will open a print dialogue with formatted data and charts.

I do not want the button to print exactly what is displayed on the screen; instead, I would like it to print a layout I define specifically for that analysis.

What is the best way to format a set of analysis and outputs in R Shiny for high resolution printing?

How can I make the button open a print dialogue for the formatted output?

---

Would it be better to use Latex + Sweave to write a new report on button click, and have the resulting PDF opened by the browser?

If so, how could I do that?